# ./ vs normal execution

Tags: macos, mac, java

This is probably a question more for unix systems but because i have it on my Mac Pro i hope i will find an answer here :

When i browse to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/db/bin`

with a cd I can't execute the command startNetworkServer present in bin , instead i can run it via `./startNetworkServer`.

However from `~`

```
MacCris:~ cris$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/db/bin/startNetworkServer
```

it works without ./

Any idea why ? (rights related ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the behaviour of your shell that is running in there Terminal.app. It is probably the [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) shell

When you ask the shell to run a command if you provide an absolute path (that is beginning with `/` as your second one does) it will try to execute that program at that path. If you provide a relative path (i.e. one not starting with `/`) it will try to create an absolute path by prepending the directories that are in your PATH environment variable to what you typed. As your current directory or `.` is not on your PATH it cannot find  a file to execute. If the path begins with a `.` the it will repave that by the absolute path of your current directory and thus get a path that can be executed.

Answer (score 2):

- `~` = home folder nothing else.
- `./something` will execute that something (be it script or binary)
  Writing the full path is the same as executing with `./`
- `cd` is change directory, so it will **not** execute

These are all standard unix/linux command line commands

**References:**
http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php
http://www.arachnoid.com/linux/shell_programming.html

Comment: Thanks...but is not that i do not know those commands (basic ones) is that the behaviour is different when i try to execute   via full path or when i am in that directory